# Quip Liveapps installation in windows 10 is not working when trying to start server and create build

Tags: quip, liveapps

While Installing the Quip Liveapps in Windows 10 , Not able to start the App with 'npm start' and 'npm run build'

while running npm start & npm run build
'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error is coming

node Js version is 10.11.0
npm version 6.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I performed some additional steps in Windows 10 and both commands are working for me. Here's my instruction, maybe it will help.

1. You must have a Quip account and be a member of a Quip site.
2. Make sure you have Node >= v6 and NPM >= v3 installed.
3. Run npm install -g create-quip-app in your terminal. 
   Depending on how you installed node you may need to run it as root with:
   sudo npm install -g create-quip-app.
4. You need to flip a flag in your browser to allow self-signed certificates on localhost for HTTPS:

   - In Chrome, copy this URL and open it in a new tab:
     chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
     Then click "Enable" and click the "Relaunch" button at the bottom of the page.
   - In Firefox and Safari, go to https://localhost:8888, then click "Advanced → Add Exception → Confirm Security Exception".

(additional steps)

5. Download python 2.7
6. Go to file create-quip-app.cmd - C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-quip-app.cmd
   Check if python exec file name is correct in first and second line (default value was python27.exe but for me it was python.exe)
7. Run npm install -g win-node-env
8. In script create-quip-app.py 
   – comment line 210 - assert path.startswith("./")
   – in methods:

   - warn_missing_paths – lines 145-146
   - is_enumerated_path – lines 172-173
     add replace
     js_filenames = set([s.replace("/", "\") for s in manifest.get("js_files", [])])
     css_filenames = set([s.replace("/", "\") for s in manifest.get("css_files", [])])